# codeginiter controller found but still 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-2

I've this following controller -

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class News extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()   {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();     

    $catid = $this->input->post('cat');

    if(isset($catid)){
        $this->filter($catid);
    }
}

private function filter($catid){
    $sql = "select * from news_master where instr(concat(',', `Category`, ','), ', $catid ,') <> 0 ";
    echo $sql;
}

}
```

It's called when form is submitted. If I submit the form, controller calls `filter` function and prints `$sql`. And strange thing is that, below it I get default 404 error message.
Here's a screenshot.! [image]

I can't understand the possible reason.

Comment: How do you get access to `News` Controller? do you use `route`?

Comment: And do not use `isset()` function to check the `post()` returned data.  The function returns `FALSE` (boolean) if the item you are attempting to retrieve does not exist. So `isset()` would return `TRUE` always.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using routes. Controller is called from *form action*. When form submitted, it goes to news controller.

Comment: What `action` are you using?

Comment: And even if I enter url in address bar directly I still get same error. Form action is - `http://localhost/custom/news`. I've htaccess to remove index.php and other controllers working fine with not mentioning index.php.

Comment: What is the `custom/`? did you create a folder inside `Controllers` Directory?

Comment: `custom` is document root folder inside `wamp/www`.

Comment: Check whether `custom/index.php/news` works?

Comment: @HashemQolami ohh.. stupid mistake. I don't have `index()` function defined. Instead I'm calling filter directly from constructor. This height of stupidity. Thanks and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No worries, BTW keep in mind my 2nd comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class News extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()   {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();     
}
public function index()
{
    $catid = $this->input->post('cat');

    if(isset($catid)){
        $this->filter($catid);
    }

}
private function filter($catid){
    $sql = "select * from news_master where instr(concat(',', `Category`, ','), ', $catid ,') <> 0 ";
    echo $sql;
}

}
```

Just noticed your calling it from the constructor function. It should be in the index function.

Answer (score 0):

Private functions dont act as pages in codeigniter

```
private function filter($catid){
    $sql = "select * from news_master where instr(concat(',', `Category`, ','), ', $catid ,') <> 0 ";
    echo $sql;
}
```

needs to be updated to PUBLIC

```
public function filter($catid){
    $sql = "select * from news_master where instr(concat(',', `Category`, ','), ', $catid ,') <> 0 ";
    echo $sql;
}
```

Comment: yes.. but I'm not calling private function directly. It's called from withing `index()` function. And even if I change to `public` error still exists.

Comment: ohh.. stupid mistake. I don't have index() function defined. Instead I'm calling filter directly from constructor. This height of stupidity. Thanks and sorry for wasting your time.